# how to install rastertospl in my usr/lib/cups/filter?

Tags: printing, samsung

For installing my Samsung ML  -1676 Printer on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS how should I add filter rastertospl on my usr/lib/cups/filter folder?

Answer (score 5):

The problem happens when you install the printer from a PPD file without using the full installer for Unified Linux Driver obtained from Samsung website.

`rastertospl` is not part of any standard apt package, you need to download 
 it from https://support.hp.com (as of 2019.09.02) or use https://www.bchemnet.com/suldr/.

Comment: Using the ULD from samsung is no option unless they provide at least a ppa. Breaks on every update. Is there any trustworthy alternative?

Comment: As of 2024-01-18: [official download page](https://support.hp.com/gb-en/drivers/swdetails/samsung-xpress-sl-m2020-laser-printer-series/16462592/swItemId/fp-194243-2) ... and [`uld_V1.00.39_01.17.tar.gz` download](https://ftp.hp.com/pub/softlib/software13/printers/SS/SL-C4010ND/uld_V1.00.39_01.17.tar.gz) .

Answer (score 2):

The archive for the Linux driver contains a *uld* directory. This directory contains the *install.sh* file and three directories: *arm*, *i386*, and *x86_64*. These directories contain the rastertospl files for different architectures. You should copy the one for your architecture in the */usr/lib/cups/filter*. Make the copy as *root* user, or you will get a permission error (from shell, use `sudo`.)

Answer (score 1):

You can go to the terminal and run :

```
sudo sh /home/yourusername/WhereverYourArchiveIs/install.sh
```

After downloading the drivers from the web, and selecting manually the .ppd file, you can go to the terminal and insert the command said before, just run the sh `"install.sh"`, found at the main folder of the ULD driver folder, as SUDO, and then you can use the printer.

If this doesn't solve your problem, go and copy the "rastertospl" file, which is found at `i386 folder` (if you are `x32 system`) or at `x86_64` (if you are `x64 system`), to the location `"usr/lib/cups/filter"` and then run the command.

That's all.

Answer (score 0):

To paste the file `rastertospl` in the folder `\usr\lib\cups\filter` you need to do this as root, otherwise the permission will be denied. Do this by right clicking on the folder filter and clicking on "Open as Root". You will notice a red stripe with Elevated Privileges written on it. Now you can paste the file `rastertospl` into the folder `\usr\lib\cups\filter`.

Comment: You could improve your answer by including what package/ppa/website provides `rastertospl`.

Comment: Where is the `rastertospl` file located?

Comment: some closed-source thing, maybe?

Answer (score 0):

The first answer was incomplete. You need to install the suld driver such as suld-driver-4.01.17 from [https://www.bchemnet.com/suldr](https://www.bchemnet.com/suldr/.).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1242314)